# The chain rule for derivatives - actual meaning

Tags: derivatives

Consider the derivative of y with respect to t:
dy/dt, according to the chain rule:

$\frac{dy}{dt} = (\frac{dy}{dx})(\frac{dx}{dt}) $

This means that the derivative of $y$ with respect to a variable $t$ is the coordinate of $y$ with respect to $x$(i.e. the slope at $x$) times the coordinate of $x$ with respect to $t$.

How would it make sense more intuitively?

Intuitively in the sense, that it would make more sense physically or well, intuitively rather than just *analytically*, i.e. just using algebraic laws, it would be rather meaningful, if it made sense in a sort of a logical argument.

And how do we take this further to the second order deriative of parametric equations:
d<sup>2</sup>y/dx<sup>2</sup> = (dy<sup>'</sup>/dt)/(dx/dt)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt , the question is similar, but the answer is not what I was looking for this question,

Comment: This is not intuitive enough for you?$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{\color{#4499de}{du}}\frac{\color{#4499de}{du}}{dx}$$

Comment: I object to the fact that two different functions are both called $y$ when we write the chain rule this way.  On the right we have a function $y$, but on the left we have a different function that for the sake of clarity needs its own name, for example $\hat y$,  The function $\hat y$ is defined by $\hat y(t) = y(x(t))$.  This is a notational problem that afflicts many presentations of the chain rule.

Comment: I think this answer gives a very clear intuition for the chain rule: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2084347/40119

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, it's analytically intuitive, (e.g. we can't relate things, may be I should had mentioned it's intuitive interpretation.

Comment: @littleO , please see my comment above, (it's the same link)

Comment: @bzal It's not even that rigorous man.  How much more could you want than cancelling fractions?!

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt , in modern era, I saw Euclid's GCD algorithm being proved using tools of abstract algebra, but during his time, he did it using only common logic(e.g. he said: "if we divide HG into FS equal parts we get AB which is equal to ......" and he PROVED his algorithm, and I found that making more sense.